# Erro de php na hora da hospedagem

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou com um problema na hora da hospedagem em um trabalho da faculdade, o problema é este aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No localhost este erro não aparece.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro referido na linha 98 do código do tema/topo é este

```
    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('success') != null){?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                          <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success');?>
                       </div>
                  <?php }?>

                  <?php if(isset($view)){echo $this->load->view($view);}?>
```

O código do controller Mapos é este:

```
    public function index() {

    $this->data['ordens'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsAbertas();
    $this->data['produtos'] = $this->mapos_model->getProdutosMinimo();
    $this->data['os'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsEstatisticas();
    $this->data['estatisticas_financeiro'] = $this->mapos_model->getEstatisticasFinanceiro();
    $this->data['menuPainel'] = 'Painel';
    $this->data['view'] = 'mapos/painel';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo',  $this->data);

}
```

O ultimo erro é de um arquivo index do codeigniter, que eu não modifiquei nada, pois ele é padrão.
Não consigo achar o que está dando este erro, todas as aplicações estão funcionando normalmente, mas se este erro não sumir, o professor não vai aceitar o trabalho. Ele já avisou que a aplicação tem de estar funcionando na hospedagem. O que eu posso fazer para sumir este erro, já que ele não está dando problema em nada da aplicação?

Answer (score 1):

Achei o erro, o manual que o professor deu para trabalhar com o codeigniter estava desatualizado, estou usando a ultima versão do framework, dai na linha 98 do código do tema/topo é este o código que estava:

```
<?php if(isset($view)){echo $this->load->view($view);}?>
```

O certo para as versões mais novas é assim:
`<?php if(isset($view)){ $this->load->view($view);}?>`
Sem o echo.